# NodeJS can new users can signup while couldnt login

Tags: node.js

I am a linux server administrator so I don't have nodejs programming experience.
The problem is that I installed nodejs for a specific laravel script for a mobile chat.

Now that I've configured everything and nodejs is running and web socket is also opened the script works but when new users signup they do it successfully while when trying to login an error (cat error) comes up.

I have verified that new signed up users added to db and that web socket is opened but I don't know why when users try to login it throws an error.
As server administrator I have checked all log files but I get nothing related to the problem.

Also enabled mysql query log and found that a sql query is already sent to mysql when trying to sign in with new created account
But I don't know why users can't sign in, that's why I suspect the backend server is not working.

Here are the lines of codes in "server.js" that is related to the problem

```
 this.handleDisconnection(), this.store.revealNames.register(this.user).catch(e => {}), this.handler(o.enc({
                publicMessageId: s,
                error: !1,
                grantedSettings: this.user.grantedSettings(),
                posts: this.store.wall.all(),
                rooms: this.store.rooms.all().map(e => e.parse(this.user, this.store.users)),
                users: this.store.users.filter(e => e.canBeSeenBy(this.user)).map(e => e.parse()),
                gifts: this.store.gifts.all(),
                faces: this.store.faces.all(),
                user: this.user.parse()
            })), this.store.radio.startListening(this.user)
        }).catch(e => {
            this.user.isLogged = !1;
            const t = {
                error: !0,
                message: "Ø­Ø¯Ø« Ø®Ø·Ø£ Ø£Ø«Ù†Ø§Ø¡ ØªØ³Ø¬ÙŠÙ„ Ø§Ù„Ø¯Ø®ÙˆÙ„, Ø§Ù„Ø±Ø¬Ø§Ø¡ Ø¥Ø¹Ø§Ø¯Ø© Ø§Ù„Ù…Ø­Ø§ÙˆÙ„Ø©"
            };
            try {
                if (e.response.data.name) return t.message = e.response.data.name, this.handler(o.enc(t));
                if (e.response.data.is_friendly_message && e.response.data.message) return t.message = e.response.data.message, this.handler(o.enc(t))
            } catch (e) {
                return this.user.isLogged = !1, this.handler(o.enc(t))
            }

            t.data.user.adminToken && this.store.adminTokens.push(t.data.user.adminToken), this.handleDisconnection(), this.user.isVirtual ? (this.store.virtualUserIds.push(this.user.reg_id), this.handler(t.data.user.defaultRoom)) : (this.store.revealNames.register(this.user).catch(e => {}), this.handler(o.enc({
                publicMessageId: r,
                error: !1,
                cookie: e,
                grantedSettings: this.user.grantedSettings(),
                posts: this.store.wall.all(),
                rooms: this.store.rooms.all().map(e => e.parse(this.user, this.store.users)),
                users: this.store.users.filter(e => e.canBeSeenBy(this.user)).map(e => e.parse()),
                gifts: this.store.gifts.all(),
                faces: this.store.faces.all(),
                user: this.user.parse()
            })), this.store.radio.startListening(this.user))
        }).catch(e => {
            this.user.isLogged = !1;
            const t = {
                error: !0,
                message: "Ø­Ø¯Ø« Ø®Ø·Ø£ Ø£Ø«Ù†Ø§Ø¡ ØªØ³Ø¬ÙŠÙ„ Ø§Ù„Ø¯Ø®ÙˆÙ„, Ø§Ù„Ø±Ø¬Ø§Ø¡ Ø¥Ø¹Ø§Ø¯Ø© Ø§Ù„Ù…Ø­Ø§ÙˆÙ„Ø©"
            };
            try {
                if (e.response.data.name) return t.message = e.response.data.name, this.handler(o.enc(t));
                if (e.response.data.password) return t.message = e.response.data.password, this.handler(o.enc(t));
                if (e.response.data.is_friendly_message && e.response.data.message) return t.message = e.response.data.message, this.handler(o.enc(t))
            } catch (e) {
                return this.user.isLogged = !1, this.handler(o.enc(t))
            }
        })
```

I get the following error

```
Ø­Ø¯Ø« Ø®Ø·Ø£ Ø£Ø«Ù†Ø§Ø¡ ØªØ³Ø¬ÙŠÙ„ Ø§Ù„Ø¯Ø®ÙˆÙ„, Ø§Ù„Ø±Ø¬Ø§Ø¡ Ø¥Ø¹Ø§Ø¯Ø© Ø§Ù„Ù…Ø­Ø§ÙˆÙ„Ø©
```

In the above code there are two blocks, I get the error when trying to log in with the registered user.
why new signed up users cannot login?

Comment: You could get better error messages but either returning or doing a `console.error` the error object you receive in the catch blocks.

That would help debugging better

Comment: the error is arabic thats why i doesnt show
but i got this error when trying to login

Comment: Thats what you are returning from the catch blocks.
`const t = { error: !0, message: "Ø...`
But you seem to be swallowing `e` which is being received in the catch block. I was referring to that

Comment: sorry i dont understand programming , only basics & i know that cath will catch error , but dont completely understand, how could this problem be solved ? is it from code or from server ?